# Applying machine learning on a point cloud dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, social-science

I have multiple 3d models in ply format. These models are archeological imprints. And I have to make a model to classify the dataset according to their imprint type. I have 4 different classes.

I use this code to parse the data. This code samples the dataset and extract the labels in a separate list.

```
def parse_dataset(num_points=2048):

    all_points = []
    all_labels = []

class_map = {}
folders = [os.path.normpath(i) for i in glob.glob("File Path")]
print(folders)

for i, folder in enumerate(folders):
    print("processing class: {}".format(os.path.basename(folder)))
    # store folder name with ID so we can retrieve later
    class_map[i] = folder.split("/")[-1]
    # gather all files
    train_files = [os.path.normpath(i) for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder,"*"))]
    #print(train_files)

for f in train_files:
        all_points.append(trimesh.load(f).sample(num_points))
        all_labels.append(i)

    
return (
    np.array(all_points),
    
    np.array(all_labels),
   
    class_map,
)
NUM_POINTS = 10000

all_points, all_labels , CLASS_MAP = parse_dataset(
NUM_POINTS
)
```

Then I split the dataset and pass them to a SVM. The problem is that the maximum accuracy I can get is 42%. As I am new to these types of files I don't know how to preprocess these files to increase my accuracy. I have a total of only 520 ply files. So i guess a deep learning model won't work well on a small dataset. Can anybody recommend any data augmentation or pre-preprocessing techniques to increase the accuracy of my model?

Comment: It would be useful to know how many classes you have. i.e. what does 42% accuracy mean? How bad is that? Can you do this task yourself by eye? What's a reasonable accuracy to ask of your model?

Comment: @SumakuTension   I have 4 different classes. I get 42% accuracy on the test data. I don't have a benchmark because it is like a research project. No i can't do this task by eye. There are subtle differences between the imprints that I want my model to identify. I want my accuracy to be a minimum 80%.

Comment: Most often, you can't expect your  model to outperform human level performance on unstructured data (especially not with as little data as you have). If you're not able to spot these differences by eye, then it's unlikely your model will pick this up. In your case a strategy could be: What feature-engineering is necessary for me to be able to correctly classify by eye. this will guide your thinking in coming up with useful features for your model